# iMessage "delivered"

Tags: iphone, messages

I sent my friend an iMessage about 4 hours ago, and the blue bubble appeared, but delivered text never appeared below the message bubble. I assume this means that the recipient did not receive the message.
I just sent them another iMessage and this time it said delivered.

Does that mean that my friend was able to receive both the messages **or** just the most recent one? And is the first message lost in transit?

Answer (score 2):

Your friend was able to receive both the messages.

The former message was not lost in transit.